# Stored session into var not persistent after session_unset & session_destroy

Tags: php, session

I try to store my PHP session into a variable like the following :

```
$old_session = $_SESSION;
```

Then I delete my session in order to create a new one.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

But when i tried to `error_log( $old_session )`, it's empty.

It seems that `session_unset()` & `session_destroy` clears everything even my `$old_session` variable's content

This code worked with php 5.5 but i'm using php 7 now, any ideas ?

**EDIT :** following advice from @RogierSpieker it seems that `session_unset` is the problem.

here is the code :

```
error_log(" INSIDE SUPSESSION BEFORE SESSION_UNSET \$old_session equal to :  " . print_r($old_session,true));
session_unset();
error_log(" INSIDE SUPSESSION AFTER SESSION_UNSET \$old_session equal to :  " . print_r($old_session,true));
```

Before `$old_session` is filled corectly but not after.

Comment: try `var_dump` or `print_r`. I tried it and the variable still has values

Comment: @monace19 var_dump return nothing `array(0) { }`

Comment: what if you use `$old_session = clone $_SESSION;` instead of `$old_session = $_SESSION;`?

Comment: You are creating a reference to `$_SESSION`, not a copy. Once you `unset`/`destroy` the session, `$_SESSION` gets truncated and therefor also the `$old_session` as this only refers to `$_SESSION`. Use

Comment: You are sure that you pass the value to `$old_session` before `session_unset();` and `session_destroy();`?

Comment: @RobinKanters can't use clone cause it's called on non-object.

Comment: @RogierSpieker use what ?

Comment: yeah @monace19 i'm sure about that

Comment: @akio You could use `foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value){$old_session[$key] = $value;}` or (as I tend to do), simply cast it into an object, like `$old_session = (object) $_SESSION;` (and realise that $old_session is an object now, not an array, which I tend to like, others maybe not so much).

Comment: @RogierSpieker unfortunaly tried to cast into an obkect but still empty after clearing `$_SESSION`

Comment: @akio you had me doubting my approach, so I just double-checked using a simple array. The casted object does not reflect changes made in the original. So it should have worked. Can you verify the `$old_session` does get affected by the `session_*` functions by dumping it using `var_dump($old_session)` before and after the `session_*` functions?

Comment: @RogierSpieker okay i done the test. Before `session_unset` `$old_session`is correctly filled, after it's empty

Comment: @akio and above those `print_r` you have `$old_session = (object) $_SESSION`?

Comment: @rogierSpieker Yes i do

Comment: the only trick i found is to cast `(object) $_SESSION` as some of you advised me then use `clone` to fill `$old_session` and finally re cast `$old_session` as `array`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103867/discussion-between-rogier-spieker-and-akio).